# Non-uniform Normal force, friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

I got problems understanding the Non-uniform normal force. Why is it non-uniform? Because the object would have different densities in different parts, so weight would be greater in some parts? So Normal Force would be aligned with weight, no? Normal force only depends the force applied on the ground, so it depends of the weight of the object, no?
why does the object can tip? It only tips if Normal Force is on the corner of the object or out of it. how come? How can normal force be applied  outside the contact surfaces? 
Try to give me some analogy to understand better please. 
[image]

Comment: Would it be at all possible for you to provide a diagram.  Put yourself in our place trying to visualize the system you are talking about.

Comment: Too many questions.  You need to ask your teacher these questions.  Or use internet tutorials like Khan Academy.  We can provide help with a specific problem, but not teach you from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

**Half of your questions are concerning Newton's law:**

> Why is it non-uniform? Because the object would have different densities in different parts, so weight would be greater in some parts?

Yes. Think of a car. It is in contact with the ground in four places and pushes down causing four normal forces. If the car is heavily loaded with bagage in the trunk, the back-wheels will carry much more load than the front-wheels. They experience a larger normal force.

Now, think of a bike where you suddenly brake hard with the front-wheel brake. You are slung forward and so is the rest of the bike, and the front wheel, is carrying much more load than the back-wheel  which is almost lifting (which would give zero normal force).

So yes, uneven normal forces are certainly possible and very usual. An uneven density as you mention is one possibility, but other factors as the above examples show can also cause uneven forces on the ground at different points.

> So Normal Force would be aligned with weight, no?

What does "aligned" mean? If you mean "normal force will balance weight", then yes it might, but be careful. That is not a law, but just one possible result of Newton's 1st law:

$$\sum F=0$$

If a car is standing on the road, then $$\sum F=n-w=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad n=w$$ Normal force balances weight, yes. But if an elephant is pulling in the it with force $F$, then $$\sum F=n+F-w=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad n=w-F$$
Normal force and weight is not related any more than any other forces are. It *just happens* to often be the case that normal force balances weight.

> Normal force only depends the force applied on the ground, so it depends of the weight of the object, no?

Normal force can depend on any force that pushes downwards, as just explained. Think of normal force as a **holding force**. It is the force a road or a table or etc. applies to hold something up - it doesn't matter *which* forces that are pushing the objects downwards (it can be weight or any other force); but *if* the objects *are* pushed downwards, then normal force will try to hold them up.

**The other half of your questions are concerning the rotational equivalent of Newton's law:**

> why does the object can tip?

If an object tips then it *rotates* about some point. We here have to introduce the rotational version of Newton's 2nd law:
$$\sum \tau=I\alpha$$

$\alpha$ is the rotational (or angular) acceleration, so if the object starts to tip over, then $\alpha$ is becoming non-zero. And when will that happen? As in Newton's 2nd law, when forces are not balanced, an object will accelerate, the likewise in this rotational version of the law, when *torques* $\tau$ are not balanced, the object will accelerate *rotationally*.

So, if e.g. in a heigh truck too much heavy load is put in one side then the centre of mass is in this side. If the truck ever tilts a little, then the centre of gravity might pass the point where the normal force on the wheel applies, and then the weight and normal force will help each other to make the truck rotate more and more since they don't balance each other anymore - so $\alpha$ is non-zero.

> It only tips if Normal Force is on the corner of the object or out of it. how come?

It's not about the corner specifically, but it's about where the centre-of-mass is location compared to where other forces, like the normal force, is pushing. All torques from all forces must be balanced at every point, otherwise the object will tip.

> How can normal force be applied outside the contact surfaces?

It can't (unless you are talking about some "equivalent" or "average" normal force. Normal force is a contact force that appears at contacting surfaces.